# Product attributes: what's the effect of scope options

Tags: product-attribute, scope

Comparing product attributes in two magento installs, I see that some attributes have a global scope in install 1, and store view scope in install 2. I haven't created these attributes myself, and I don't know if there was a special reason to do this.

Now I wonder what the effect is of this setting.

---

Edit: at first I wrote "system scope" instead of "global scope", because it was translated like that for my language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default attribute set contains all of the system Attributes that are required for each Product

The orange circles mark the System Attributes. Recall that every set must contain all of the System Attributes because each Product must have all of the System Attributes applied to it.

You cannot delete a Group that has System Attributes in it.

### Update

If you are talking about attribute scopes than [this manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/understanding-store-scopes) should help.

Comment: I see that I should have used "global scope" instead of "system scope", because of a confusing translation. That may change your answer, because it doesn't make sense to me like this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: In System > Config: Store email addresses you can set different addresses on three levels: default, website and shop. This use I understand. I don't understand how or why an attribute should be different on different levels.

Comment: The attributes on all levels are the same but their values which will be used depend on current scope.

Comment: Thanks! I suddenly got that light bulb moment. I was looking from the wrong perspective. These are attributes for products, like color, and that can be set for each product on global, website or store level, limited by this setting.

Comment: The link to the manual is dead. :(