# Could not get custom attribute in product listing

Tags: price, adminhtml, product-list, store-view, custom-attributes

I have custom price attribute called `wholesale_price`.

The `wholesale_price` is only needed for one of the store view. So i choose specific store view, then update the `wholesale_price`.

The problem is:
    I can get the `wholesale_price` variable through `$_product->getWholesalePrice()` in product view page but not in product listing page.
In product listing page, the `$_product->getWholesalePrice()` is empty.

Eventually, after i tried to save it from default store view. The `wholesale_price` is available in the product listing page.

So everytime i need to update the price, i need to go by saving from default store, and it is annoying.

Could you please tell me what is the code difference between saving from default store view and the others store view?

Thank you!

Comment: what is scope of your attribute ? and it should be Used in Product Listing selected as "Yes"

Comment: I cannot set price scope, and i have set the Product Listing to 'Yes'

Comment: i am asking for your custom attribute scope read [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14049/product-attributes-whats-the-effect-of-scope-options) and [here](https://understandinge.com/forum/product-attribute-questions/global-website-store-view-for-attribute/)

Comment: My bad for not writing it clearly. When you set the attribute type to `Price` then the scope attributes is hidden. I am running magento 1.9

Comment: have you tried indexing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I get is using the `saveAfter` event and explicitly set default store `WholesalePrice` to be updated.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), $attributes , 0);
```

Thank you guys for your help.